# Partial page scanning

Tags: scanner

We have about 30,400 sheets of paper. Each sheet of paper has an ID that is written by hand as shown in picture:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/46620806@N05/8677946233/in/photostream/lightbox/

I'm just wondering if there is any scanner that allows me to scan just that ID for each paper and will store those numbers in a text file. It's about a partial page scanning, but I'm not sure if I have to look for a scanner or a software.

Comment: This type of thing should (considering you have 30,400 Sheets you want to scan) NOT be done in handwriting. You never know if the handwriting recognition has read a wrong number etc. So instead generate a simple barcode for the id and have that be scanned, 100% reliability and most scanners today have barcode recognition built into their scanner software.

Comment: @M.Bennett - Are you suggesting to manually read and convert the handwritten numbers into a barcode for all 30,400 pages? I think it would be easier to manually read and transcribe the numbers by hand, but that is what the OP is trying to avoid... manual operations on each of 30,400 pages.

Comment: @M.Bennett: While I agree with your comment regarding OCR accuracy 100%, it might not be advisable or even possible to redo all that work. Let's just concentrate on a solution to the OP's request for partial page scanning, and leave the headache of proofreading to him.